# Windows Driver NONPNP Signing

Tags: windows, driver, msdn

I have tried to run the NONPNP windows driver code. It installs and when I run the nonpnpapp.exe  I get a driver signing error.

```
"windows requires a digitally signed driver"
```

I am running this on debug mode and release I am test signing it.

Why am I still getting this error? 
I do know that x64 machines needs this, I am on windows7 x64.

So we need to do something else.

Visual studio output says that the `sys` file is successfully signed.

I trace the code. It copies the `sys` to `system32/drivers` after it is signed.

Comment: Is it test signed? In that case you need to enable your machine to allow test signing.

Comment: Thanks Rohan. You have been very helpful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484(v=vs.85).aspx

this did it.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows device installation uses digital signatures to verify the integrity of driver packages and to verify the identity of the vendor (software publisher) who provides the driver packages. In addition, the kernel-mode code signing policy for 64-bit versions of Windows Vista and later versions of Windows specifies that a kernel-mode driver must be signed for the driver to load.+
>   Note Windows 10 for desktop editions (Home, Pro, Enterprise, and Education) and Windows Server 2016 kernel-mode drivers must be signed by the Windows Hardware Dev Center Dashboard, which requires an EV certificate. For details, see Driver Signing Changes in Windows 10. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/driver-signing

Two options there;

1)  [allow test signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/the-testsigning-boot-configuration-option)

2) [disable driver signature enforcement](https://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/)

If you are using a dedicated test machine, I recommend the second option since I think it's more error proof.